# Pandas: groupby and make a new column by concatenating the result

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I want to know how to create a new column after groupby and apply sum calculation.

I have a data frame like this.

```
> df
tour_id  time  condA  condB  condC
      1    10   True   True   True
      1    20   True   True   True
      1    30  False  False  False
      1    40  False  False  False
      2    15   True   True   True
      2    25  False  False  False
      2    30  False  False  False
      2    45  False  False  False
      2    50   True   True   True
```

I want to

1. groupby `tour_id` and take a sum of `time` column where `condA` and `condB` and `condC` are all `False`. Like below.

   ```
   tour_id    sum
         1     70
         2    100
   ```
2. Merge the result of 1 to the original data frame `df`, filling with the same value in a group, and name this new column as `driving`.

so the result should look like:

```
tour_id  time  condA  condB  condC  driving
      1    10   True   True   True       70
      1    20   True   True   True       70
      1    30  False   False False       70
      1    40  False   False False       70
      2    15   True   True   True      100
      2    25  False  False  False      100
      2    30  False  False  False      100
      2    45  False  False  False      100
      2    50   True   True   True      100
```

My attempt:

```
temp = df[(df.condA == True)&(df.condB == True) &(df.condC == True)]
df2 = temp.groupby('tour_id').time.sum().reset_index()
```

But I don't know how to merge `df2` to the original `df`.

Comment: For you example, tour_id of 1 should correspond to 70, not 80

Comment: there was a mistake in the question. it's already fixed. thank you very much for spotting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['driving'] = df['tour_id'].map(df[~df[['condA','condB','condC']].all(1)].groupby('tour_id')['time'].sum())
```

Yields:

```
   tour_id  time  condA  condB  condC  driving
0        1    10   True   True   True       70
1        1    20   True   True   True       70
2        1    30  False  False  False       70
3        1    40  False  False  False       70
4        2    15   True   True   True      100
5        2    25  False  False  False      100
6        2    30  False  False  False      100
7        2    45  False  False  False      100
8        2    50   True   True   True      100
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! but sorry, I made a mistake by wrongly aggregated time where all the conditions are True, not False. I modified the question. In case of adding up Falses, how should I change `all(1)`?

Comment: See my edit, you can simply insert a `~` to indicate NOT (i.e. False).

Comment: ah it was that simple! thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using `all` to filter the data frame

```
df['driving']=df.tour_id.map(df[(df.iloc[:,-3:]).all(1)].groupby('tour_id').time.sum())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! but sorry, I made a mistake by wrongly aggregated time where all the conditions are True, not False. I modified the question. In this case how does your answer change?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your groupby dataframe into a dict, and then map the tour_id column through it:

```
df['driving'] = df.tour_id.map(temp.groupby('tour_id').time.sum().to_dict())
```